# I want to checked the checkbox by matching the value from mongo database

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, mongodb

this code is written in the handlebars and I'm using mongodb with nodejs and I want to edit the admin profile in which I need the values checkbox to be selected which we will get from the database need to compare and checked the checkbox

```
<pre>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label text-bold mr-6" style=" ">User Management
<input type="checkbox" name="role" value="User Management" class="chk" />
</label>
<label class="control-label text-bold mr-6" style=" ">Payment Management
<input type="checkbox" name="role" value="Payment Management" class="chk" />
</label>
<label class="control-label text-bold mr-6" style=" ">Booking Management
<input type="checkbox" name="role" value="Booking Management" class="chk" />
</label>
<label class="control-label text-bold mr-6" style=" ">Cancellation Management
<input type="checkbox" name="role" value="Cancellation Management" class="chk" />
</label>
<label class="control-label text-bold mr-6" style=" ">Club Management
<input type="checkbox" name="role" value="Club Management" class="chk" />
</label>
<label class="control-label text-bold mr-6" style=" ">Report Management
<input type="checkbox" name="role" value="Report Management" class="chk" />
</label>
<label class="control-label text-bold mr-6" style=" ">Static Pages Management
<input type="checkbox" name="role" value="Static Pages Management" class="chk"  />
</label>
</div>
</pre>
```

[i am providing my front end side in which i want these checkboxes to be checked the selected values is shwoing in the role box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wWex.png)

Answer (score 0):

1 - And so,
Load the data from mongo DB first , wait for it to load and add the props to the input element:

```
<input [...other_props] checked={mongo_db_data_field_value} />
```

if you do not know how to put the value dynamically,

use js createElement('html_element_tag_name') and set all the props you need like :

```
var label1 = document.createElement('label');
...set the props of the label
var input1 = document.createElement('input');
...set other props of the input
input1.checked = mongoData.field_field_value;
```

and group your label and input within another tag like div, give an ID prop to the div and :

```
document.getElementById('div_parent_id').innerHtml = '';
document.getElementById('div_parent_id').appendChild(label1);
document.getElementById('div_parent_id').appendChild(input1);
```

or for fewer code :

2 - give an id to your inputs and just do this :

```
document.getElementById('input_id').checked = mongo_data_field_value
```

Comment: I didnt get you can u please do this solution with my code i tried to add the check field with mongo parameter but now all the check box are selected please do this with my code so tht will be better for me to understand

Comment: can u tell me how i can get my db data in script tag like i m using handlebars so if i m getting data on a parameter name role {{role}} if i use this i can fetch all the data but if i m doing this same thing in script tag its unable to fetch the data there

Comment: What is the type of your db field value ? string | bool | integer | ?

if it is string like "yes", "no" => you need to test the value as :
every string give always true in boolean, even if an empty string "".

var input_checked = false;
if (db_value === "yes") { input_checked = true; }

if the value is boolean that good,

if the value is integer , every integer bigger than Zero give true in boolean,

the prop checked of input need boolean value so true or false.

Comment: Fetching data is another things,
Are you using server side web services or what you use to fetch mongo db data ?

The logic is you need server side (backend) rest API or GraphQL endpoint, and you fetch the data through the endpoint url by using AJAX, ApolloClient, JS fetch API or other library you want .

fetching data is generally async AND you need to wait for before using it.